# Delete unused measures in Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, simplify, measure

I have to take charge of power bi's reports and there are really a lot of measures. Many of them are test measures that are useless and I would like to delete all unused measures. Is there a method to do this easily or should each page of the report be reviewed for each measure if it is used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Radacad has created a power bi cleanup tool. This should do what you require. 
[PowerBI Helper](http://radacad.com/power-bi-cleanup-tool-time-saving-with-power-bi-helper)

Answer (score 2):

Radcad's tool is good, but it won't actually let you delete the measures. It shows you the tables that aren't used in the visualizations so you can hide them. But I can't find a way to see any unused measures, much less delete them.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Model view -> under Fields, select multiple measures to be deleted by holding CTRL/Shift key, press delete button. I encountered the same issue and resolved it by changing the view in Power Bi. I hope this is applicable on your end too.

Answer (score 1):

I found this online... it looks like it might be a useful hack.

With the option Enter Data, you can quickly create a new empty table to place your test measures.
After testing, move the correct measures to a final table and remove the test table with all other measures.
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Best-way-to-delete-multiple-measures-in-tables/td-p/415716

Answer (score 1):

This feature is already available in the model view.

If you go to the model view, by clicking on expand button for the data table where you want to delete a group of measures the list of all columns and measures will be displayed. Then you can use CTRL or shift buttons to select multiple measures. After the desired selection, by right clicking over it you have an option "Delete from model" to delete the selected measures at once.

Hope this solves your problem.